# APIM policy 'Validate-header' is failing for 'Permissions-Policy' header even its valid value

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

My backend is emitting the below value for `Permissions-Policy` header and its clearly a string.

```
"accelerometer=(),ambient-light-sensor=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),encrypted-media=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),midi=(),payment=(),picture-in-picture=(),speaker=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=(),vr=()"
```

And I have below APIM policy to validate my headers

```
<validate-headers specified-header-action="prevent" unspecified-header-action="ignore" />
```

But APIM is throwing an exception with the below error:

```
The response cannot contain multiple values for the header `Permissions-Policy`.
```

Strangely, below the `set-header` policy where I am overriding the `Permissions-Policy` header with the same value works!

```
<set-header name="Permissions-Policy" exists-action="override">
    <value>@("accelerometer=(),ambient-light-sensor=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),encrypted-media=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),midi=(),payment=(),picture-in-picture=(),speaker=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=(),vr=()")</value>
</set-header>
```

To me, this looks like a bug in APIM maybe.

Comment: can you share your complete policy

Comment: Can you please be more specific?
If you are asking for the whole APIM XML with all policies, sorry I cannot share that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I have reproduced the issue at my environment with few modifications and it worked for me***

**`Policy:`**

```
<validate-headers  specified-header-action="prevent"  unspecified-header-action="ignore"  />
```

Even I have got the same error as you wherein my response header was created in the following way

[image]

[image]

But then I have removed the type input **string** and saved with blank value like below

[image]

Then it worked for me

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Trace:`**

No errors in outbound section.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this issue.
I am checking with Azure support as well. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1342366/apim-policy-validate-header-is-failing-for-permiss?comment=question#comment-1344013

Comment: changing it to an array also worked.